# How to differentiate between an unexpected error and planned rejection in angular promises?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

If I understand correctly (promises API is very confusing), any error occurred in a promise is suppressed, so the following code:

```
$http.post(...)
    .then(data => {
      if (data.noGood) {
        return $q.reject();
      } else {
        // Some bug.
        var a = {};
        return a.a.a > 3;
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('bad data');
    });
```

is buggy, as `badData` is not necessarily true if `'bad data'` is logged).

The desired behaviour for me is to see a console error upon every real runtime error, and leave handling rejections to me. Am I missing something here? What is the correct approach?

Checking if the error is `Error` on each `catch` block seems tedious.

Comment: Other promise implementation are [much better debuggable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25827234/how-to-debug-javascript-promises)

Answer (score 0):

Unless the rejection was explicitly constructed from `Error` class or its child, rejections can be differentiated by their types.

```
.catch(error => {
  if (!(error instanceof Error))
    console.error(error)
});
```

Exceptions from `$q` promises are handled by [`$exceptionHandler` service and logged by default](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.7/src/ng/exceptionHandler.js#L49), even if they are caught with `catch`. Without `error instanceof Error` type check `console.error(error)` will result in logging them twice.

Despite `reject` and `throw` [are used interchangeably](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33445415/javascript-promises-reject-vs-throw) most of the times, for `$q` promises it makes sense to `reject` rejection reasons and `throw` errors as `Error` objects to keep this scheme working.

Comment: In a jasmine test I'm seeing errors suppressed (not logged) when there is a `catch` after `then`. It seems the link you provided is talking about angular expression errors, i.e. in HTML templates.

Comment: @Uri It talks about any kind of JS errors that may happen inside Angular app callbacks (except SyntaxError that cannot be caught). The question doesn't touch upon Jasmine or testing. Any way, this is not true. When ngMock is loaded, it brings its [own implementation of $exceptionHandler](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/provider/$exceptionHandlerProvider) that rethrows exceptions from $exceptionHandler to Jasmine. [see here](http://plnkr.co/edit/9RkyIQ1KYuFQi5QEM9n9?p=preview). This behaviour is configurable with $exceptionHandlerProvider.