# Node.js - TypeError callback is not a function

Tags: node.js

i want yours help

**stamp.js**

```
var CoinStack = require('coinstack-sdk-js')
const crypto = require('crypto');


var client = new CoinStack('c7dbfacbdf1510889b38c01b8440b1', 
'10e88e9904f29c98356fd2d12b26de');


var privateKeyWIF = CoinStack.ECKey.createKey(); //개인키 생성
console.log('개인키 : '+ privateKeyWIF)


const message = "Hello, world";
var data = new Array();
data = Buffer.byteLength(message, 'utf8')
const hash = crypto.createHmac('sha256', data.toString()).digest('hex');
console.log("hash : ", hash)
console.log('')


var stampId = client.stampDocument(privateKeyWIF, hash);
console.log(stampId)
console.log('')[enter image description here][1]
```

[image: Error 1]

[image: Error 2]

I don't know what to do,

i want your ideas

Comment: You can get more information about the promise by listening to `unhandledRejection`. This will help you find where exactly the code is breaking. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43834559/how-to-find-which-promises-is-unhandled-in-nodejs-unhandledpromiserejectionwarni

Comment: It seems like some of the methods you are calling expect a callback function to be provided. I can't see anything other than the stampDocument function, which is not documented on the coinstack-sdk-js npm repo. If a function expects a callback parameter, it needs to pass it in, else by default it will be undefined.