# how to find occurrences of unfulfilled promises in my javascript code?

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

Assume I have somewhere in my javascript code `async function doSomething() {}` and somewhere else I call this function without trying to fulfill it.

Just `doSomething();` Not `await doSomething()`. (neither `doSomething().then()`).
How do I find all these occurrences?

I just spent 10 hours chasing after an unknown promise that got resolved at some random point due to a missing `await` before the function call. I wish there is a way to find them all.

Comment: You could consider something like TypeScript, but I don't know of any way for static code analysis to discover these problems.

Comment: If you use a type-checker, that'll help you - that way, for example, you'll be sure of whether something is a `Promise` or some other value

Comment: I thought it's an interesting enough question, a mistake I could easily see happening, and I can't think of an easy-ish way to solve it off the top of my head without seriously changing things around.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30564053/how-can-i-synchronously-determine-a-javascript-promises-state

Comment: I think there's a decent question in here, if it's reworded around how to debug or avoid this class of bugs, and refrains from asking about a specific "scan" tool. - For instance, you could induce failure, and [check for unhandled reections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43994999/918910). One more comment: you say it's "unfulfilled" in one place, but "resolved" in another which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks Jib. I edited the question to be more about how to find these cases and not about finding a scan tool. I'm not looking for unhandled rejections but unhandled promises in general.

Comment: @CertainPerformance, I do use Flow, but it didn't complain about it for some reason.