# NodeJS warning because of Promise

Tags: node.js

So I am trying to figure out what part of my nodejs script is causing this warning to appear

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 4)
```

The issue is that Node is not telling me what line this is being triggered at - So I don't know how to fix it.

And I would really like to fix it before it becomes a bigger problem.

Is there away to get NodeJS to put line number when a warning like this is triggered?

Comment: The problem is that nodejs doesn't know what line number caused the problem.  It finds out after the fact that a promise rejected and there was no handler for that rejection.  Usually, there is some context about what operation is involved and code inspection can identify possible culprits.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43834559/how-to-find-which-promises-are-unhandled-in-node-js-unhandledpromiserejectionwar - This answer solved my issue

Comment: So, if you now have an answer to your question, then either delete your question or post an answer to your own question or mark it a duplicate of that other question.  You shouldn't just leave it hanging out here with no answers if your problem is now solved.

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43834559/how-to-find-which-promises-are-unhandled-in-node-js-unhandledpromiserejectionwar