# Axios in nodejs can't make request

Tags: node.js, axios

What am I doing wrong in this GET method?

I'm making a GET request from an external API in my API controller.

but when performing the request, I get this error in my terminal:

```
 node:internal/process/promises:279
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

[UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "AxiosError: Request failed with status code 404".] {   
  code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION'
```

That's the code:

```
    static async getCentroMontagemByLoc(req, res) {
    const { cep, raio } = req.query;

    const response = await axios
      //pdr?cep=89245000&raio=40000
      .get(`${apiCentroMontagem}/pdr?cep=${cep}&raio=${raio}`, {
        httpsAgent,
      }).catch(err => res.send(err))

    res.status(200).json(response.data);
  }
```

EDIT(return the same error):

```
try {
      await axios.get(`${apiCentroMontagem}/pdr?cep=${cep}&raio=${raio}`, {
        httpsAgent,
      }).then(response => response.data)
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
```

This is the url I'm making the request:

```
http://localhost:8080/centro-de-montagem/position?cep=joinville&raio=4000
```

this is an error returned in the browser when trying to access this function:

```
[Fiddler] ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a complete response for this request. Server returned 0 bytes.
```

however, when making the request in the source API without going through the controller, it returns the request data ( it's not a 404 status, after all there is content on this endpoint )

What am I doing wrong in this GET method?

Comment: you're doing your `catch` wrong the error you see is saying that you have an error which is not handled because you doint have a catch statement, use `trycatch`  like `try {axios.get(....)} catch(err) {console.log(err)}` and see the specific error

Comment: It keeps returning me the same error present in this post ;(

Comment: can you update the code in the post?

Comment: @MohamedOraby the `.catch()` is chained, that's perfectly fine (there _is_ an issue with sending two responses in case of errors being thrown, though, but that would not cause an Axios error).

Comment: @VitoSandrin did you try removing the `httpsAgent`?

Comment: @robertklep Yes! keeps return the same error. in httpsAgent just set "rejectUnauthorized: false"

Comment: You say you made the request to the source API without going through the controller. Did you do that with Node.js code, or with another method (Postman, cURL, browser, ...)?

Comment: @robertklep didn't say it was causing an axios error, the way it is written like `const x = async axios.get().then().catch()` he is using an async function without a `catch block` which means there is no place to catch the actual error

Comment: @MohamedOraby what do you think the `.catch()` does?

Comment: @robertklep yes, I made a request in API Client's (imnsonia, postman) and via browser, and everything is ok

Comment: @MohamedOraby would that throw an `AxiosError`?

Comment: @VitoSandrin it doesn't really make sense that you're getting a 404 error that is uncaught, while your code is clearly catching Axios errors. Are you sure there isn't some other part of your app that might be causing this error?

Comment: @robertklep Sure, because it's just this controller function that is returning an error, all the others are ok. OBS: I tried to make the request also with node-fetch, and the funny thing is that it returns the same error at the end of the log "AxiosError: Request failed with status code 404". Even if I make the request with a fetch instead of using axios...

Comment: @VitoSandrin that points to another issue then.  Perhaps it's the text of the actual response you receive from the API? Or there's another part of your app (perhaps a middleware) that's actually causing the error, and not your controller.

Comment: @robertklep I also thought that it could be a middleware, I disabled all on that endpoint. I synthesized my code to the maximum to debug and the error comes exactly from the request function. Cracking my head here trying to understand huahua

Comment: @VitoSandrin
can you double check the url you are passing to to axios ? 
you are making request to `/pdr` endpoint where as at end of your question you mentioned url
`http://localhost:8080/centro-de-montagem/position?cep=joinville&raio=4000`

Comment: @VitoSandrin see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43994999) and its comments: it might be useful to add that `unhandledRejection` handler to your app to see if you get a better insight on where the error originates.

Answer (score -1):

You are doing the catch wrong.
instead of this:

```js
try {
      await axios.get(`${apiCentroMontagem}/pdr?cep=${cep}&raio=${raio}`, {
        httpsAgent,
      }).then(response => response.data)
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
```

do this:

```js
axios.get(`${apiCentroMontagem}/pdr?cep=${cep}&raio=${raio}`, {
    httpsAgent,
}).then(response => console.log(response.data))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

source: https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/v1.x/README.md

[image: example]

Comment: It keeps returning me the same error present in this post ;(

Comment: `try/catch` and `.then().catch()` are interchangeable.

Comment: @VitoSandrin could you give more detail? just edited my answer and it seems working fine

Comment: @BlueBeret please read the comments under the main question for more details.

Comment: @VitoSandrin it should be working, just make sure you save the file before trying to run the code.

Comment: @BlueBeret I sure saved, thanks